# NGINX Websocket 302 (redirect) error

Tags: redirect, nginx, websocket, sinatra

http://prntscr.com/coliya -Chrome
http://prntscr.com/coljez -Opera

NGINX

```
  server {

  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  ssl on;
  sslcertificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
  sslcertificatekey /etc/ssl/private/budokai-onlinecom.key;
  sslciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-        SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kED$
  ssldhparam /etc/ssl/private/dhparmas.pem;
  sslpreferserverciphers on;
  sslprotocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  if ($sslprotocol = "") {
  rewrite ^ https://$host$requesturi? permanent;

  }
 largeclientheader_buffers 8 32k;
 location / {

 proxyhttpversion 1.1;

 proxysetheader Accept-Encoding "";
 proxysetheader X-Real-IP $remoteaddr;
 proxysetheader Host $host;
 proxysetheader X-Forwarded-For $proxyaddxforwardedfor;
 proxysetheader XFORWARDEDPROTO https;
 proxysetheader X-NginX-Proxy true;
 proxybuffers 8 32k;
 proxybuffersize 64k;
 proxysetheader Upgrade $httpupgrade;
 proxysetheader Connection "Upgrade";
 proxyreadtimeout 86400;
 proxypass http://budokai-online.com:8080 ;

}
```

The problem I'm having is that some computers and some browsers are being redirected when trying to get a connection to the websocket. When that 302 error shows up, the '/*' routes has been activated! This route redirects the user to the login page as you saw in the redirect response.The websocket upgrade request is turned into an ordinary http request somehow, somewhere! This seems to be where the problem is. What can be causing this?

Comment: suggest u enable the debug logs and share that it that will give insight into what is really happening.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/cont58  http://prntscr.com/contv1  http://prntscr.com/conu51

Comment: It looks okay... Do you have `map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }` in the `http` context as they do in the NGINX tutorial? Also, if your app is sitting on the same server as NGINX (which I assume it is looking at the debug) then use the loopback interface instead (127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem but it was related to varnish settings. if you are using varnish add:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.upgrade ~ "(?i)websocket") {
        return (pipe);
    }
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    if (req.http.upgrade) {
        set bereq.http.upgrade = req.http.upgrade;
        set bereq.http.connection = req.http.connection;
    }
}
```

check this link for reference:
https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/users-guide/vcl-example-websockets.html